# Хвост — хватать

Tags: однокоренные-слова

У меня, может быть, глупый вопрос. Но интересно, слова "хвост" и "хватать" родственные или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос отнюдь не глупый. Подобное предположение не противоречит ни структуре, не видимой форме слов и гораздо правдоподобнее многих других, на чистом созвучии основанной.

Однако на имеющемся уровне анализа родство не подтверждается. Хвост - восходит к очень древним индоевропейским морфам с широким кругом значачений "то, что можно держать, хватать", собственно хватать и хвост - родственны. 
(по Фасмеру)
http://www.onlineslovari.com/etimologicheskiy_slovar_russkogo_yazyika_maksa_fasmera/page/hvost.14888/

Хвастать - гораздо более молодое образование, чисто славянское, звукоподражательное, первоначально означавшее "болтать", как бы пародирующее пусточзвучие и образованное по типу "балякать", "лялякать".

Comment: А причем тут "хвастать"?

Comment: gecube, прошло столько времени...  
Если я правильно помню, кто-то из любителей удалять свои комментарии "после драки", связывал хвост с хвастать.

Answer (score 1):

хвост восходит к очень древнему русскому корню "ость".  его значение--слишком общее. Похоже - одна из разновидностей того, что сегодня называют палкой.  ость это и кончик бревна, это мостовые(мост) которые стелили остатками от строевого леса. сам остаток, кость, и масса других слов с этим корнем.
к  глаголу "хватать" никакого отношения хвост не имеет.
слово "хвастать" идет от кваса и результаты выпивона оного в большом количестве.
Это логически следует после принятия спиртного, в том или ином виде.
Если некоторым, сильно замороченным этимологией от Фасмера, не в тему тема спиртного, могу добавить, что в Западной Европе в большинстве словарей, а в частности словарь ГУГЛ, приводится масса синонимов, основной из которых  BRAG-хвастаться. По-русски это бражка. А есть и еще масса слов в различных языках-в том числе и откровенным русским матом, характеризующих состояние вралей после принятия напитка.

Хвастаться
хвастаться хва́стать(ся) хвасту́н, укр. хваста́ти, хвасту́н, сербохорв. хва̏стати, хва̏ста̑м "хвастаться, болтать", словен. hvastáti, hvastȃm, чеш. chvastati, слвц. сhvаstаt᾽sа. Возм., первонач. значило "болтать", звукоподражательное, аналогично чеш. žvast "болтовня", žvastati, žvástati "тараторить, болтать"; см. Бернекер I, 407; Ильинский, ИОРЯС 20, 4, 181. По мнению Махека ("Slavia", 16, 177), родственно др.-инд. kátthatē "хвастает" и содержит экспрессивное х-, но см. Майрхофер 148 и сл.Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

что значит звукоподражательное, одному Фасмеру известно, а также и экспрессивное Х.

Никакой этимологии Фасмер не дал, привел сравнительный анализ однокоренных слов славянских языков, и на этом вся этимология закончилась.
почему болтать, у него даже первопричины нет. одно гадание.

АНГЛИЙСКИЙ—BREG-   бражка  и  ОТ НАШЕГО БРЕШЕШЬ, БРЕХАТЬ.  Boasting—остаток от хвастун. boast->busta  бюст    как результат похвальбы, в славянских –поприще. По плечо.

АФРИКААНС---pocherij ---ОТ НАШЕГО ПОХЕРИТЬ
Валлийский—frolio, brolio – от нашего враль

В китайском—Piǎn    ну, в пьяном виде это и делают, как правило.
в гуджарати -Baḍā'ī hāṅkō   а ханка--наркотик.
В немецком –prahlen—враль
Норвежский –skryte  -- от нашего скрыть, скрытый –правду скрывает.
в греческом -kaf̱chiémai    ковш имае.
Румынский –lăuda, от нашего лажа, и залудить, луда.  Обманка.
Эстонский  - praalivad   очень похоже на проливать, заливать. Но от враль через немецкий.
Во всех славянских—от хвала, самохвальство.

Сербский    хвалисање
словенский  hvalil
болгарский –самохвалство
боснийский  hvalisanje
польский  przechwalać
хорватский hvalisati

Русское бахвальство—от хвалиться. Особо хвалиться.

Выходит русское хвастаться от хвалы и стати, после кваса...
Есть некоторое сходство с хвостом, однако корневого хвост нет ни в одном из европейских слов. Что не дает права на использование в качестве основного корня.
Правда хвастать можно и мехом от хвоста, на шапке или плечах, но это уже вторично.

От хвалы---квалификация. Тут надо особо отметить, в результате многих исследований в том числе и наших ученых(Фоменко, Носовский, Габович, ) замечены значительные огрехи в описании модели современной "классической" истории. А анализ языков, только подтверждает факт значительных временных разбросов "общепринятых" датировок и факт множественных наложений описываемых событий. А по сему, латынь-не произведение "древнего Рима", а эсперанто монахов позднего (15-17 веков) средневековья.

qua-libet adv. (тж. раздельно) 1) (se. parte) где угод- 
угодно, везде PI, Vr, Q; 2) (sc. ratione) как угодно, каким 
угодно образом, всячески Ctl.

Трахает.

qualis, e 1) какой (rei natura q. sit, quaerimus С; 
q. vir, talis oratio C): quid et quale С предмет (обсужде- 
(обсуждения) и его свойство; qualia С свойства, качества; 2) поэт, 
(= qualiter) как, словно: qualis populea maerens Phi- 
Philomela sub umbra amissos queritur fetus V словно фило- 
филомела (соловей), горестно оплакивающая в тени тополя 
утрату своих птенцов. 
qualis-cumque, qualecumque adj. какой бы ни, любой, 
какой угодно С, L, T etc. 
qualis-libet, qualelibet adj. какой угодно С etc. 
qualis-nam, qualenam adj. какой же (именно) Ар. 
qualls-qualis, qualequale Dig = qualiscumque. 
qualitas, atis f [qualis] 1) качество, свойство С etc.; 
2) характер, природа Sen, Q etc.; 3) грам. наклонение Q. 
qualitativus, a, um качественный Egcl.

Чем качественней наврешь, тем лучше.

Ишь ты какой!!!

qualiter [qualis] как, словно Col,M, РМ, О: q. q. Dig 
каким бы (то ни было) образом, так или иначе. 
qualiter-cumque как бы ни, каким бы то ни было 
образом Col.

qua-lubet apx. v. I.— qualibet.

Насчет архаизма не надо, любит и ебет= это одно и тоже.

qualum, T n Cato, Col= qualus. 
qualus, I m корзинка, плетёнка (преим. для шерсти, 
пряжи и т. д.) Cato, V, Н.

и что интересно que—queentia, ae / [queo] умение, возможность, способ- 
способность Q.                                                                                                         потенция, не иначе.

Ну и в довершении в чешском просто удар по противникам выводить этимологию хвастовства от чего угодно, но только не от выпивки.

Хвастать хвалиться—соответственно -- vychloubat se
Vychloubání

Абзац.